# scheduling to run node.js files

Tags: node.js

I want to run my node.js file automatically everyday.So when i explored regarding it i found that the node-schedule package can be used.
I installed the package using the command npm install node-schedule

then i tried the following code

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('10 * * * *', function(){
    console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

when i run this file i expected that 'The answer to life, the universe, and everything!' this will be printed in console every 10 seconds
but when i tried running this file I didn't get anything in my console.

please help me out

Comment: Your 10 is minutes not seconds. `10 * * * *` - At every 10th minute past every hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schedule format is wrong if u want to run every 10 seconds. Should be like this instead

`*/10 * * * * *`

**Tested on node-schedule 0.6.0. NodeJS version: 0.10.29**